# How to solve gspread API ReadTimeout limit (Python)?

Tags: python, error-handling, gspread, timeoutexception

I am using gspread module to read data from a google sheet, however, some gsheets are somehow too large, and whenever i try to  read(get) the values from the google sheet i get a timeout error as the following:

**ReadTimeout**: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sheets.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)

One solution comes to my mind is to extend the timeout value ,which i don't know exactly how.
If you know how, or have any kind of solution to this issue, I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you look at [gspread repository](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/987/commits/ff57b8b2ddf520222db3cdfd962077e450cbb8eb) it recently merged a new PR that introduces timeouts in the client. When released, just update gspread to latest version and you'll be able to set a timeout on you requests.